# Using pivot in one select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have table with columns:

```
[Date]       [Name]     [Result]
2010-01-01   Name01     11
2010-01-01   Name02     22
2010-07-04   Name01     32
2010-07-04   Name02     54
```

I'm working on SELECT statement which give me a result like this:

```
[Name]  [2010-01-01] [2010-07-04]
Name01       11           32
Name02       22           54
```

I've tried PIVOT function, but it's not working.

SELECT * FROM (

```
SELECT Date,Name,Result
FROM tbl_Results
WHERE (..conditions..)
)
PIVOT (
Result FOR Date in
([1],[2],[3],[2],[5])
)
```

Error message

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'PIVOT'.

It's SQL server 2005, I'm not sure if PIVOT is available?

Maybe use any other function ?

Also I don't know how to set column name as date from select.

#### UPDATE

Thank you for all answers. The problem is that I don't know how many columns will be in the result. So I can't use fixed dates values like '2010-07-04'. The date is used "on the fly" in statement from table.

Comment: `PIVOT` was available in SQL Server 2005, however, 2005 so long out of support. I would really advise looking at upgrade paths. As for your query, you've removed some of it, and I suspect that the error is in the redacted SQL.

Comment: Larnu, thank you for quick response. I realize upgrade is nessesary. But also the application is written in asp.net 2.0 and right now is on a shared hosting (IIS server). So it should be moved, app & database to new server. As I red in articles, it's not possible to make a conversion from asp.net 2.0 to asp.net core in automated way. Probably should by write as new project from the scratch..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see in your update that you will need DYNAMIC SQL.   Here is a stored procedure that will pivot virtually any table, or ad-hoc query.   There is also the added utility of creating additional row aggregations

**Example**

```
Exec [prc-Pivot] '#YourTable','Date','sum([Result])[]','Name','count(*)[Records],min(Result)[MinValue],max(Result)[MaxValue]'
```

**Or As Simple As**

```
Exec [prc-Pivot] '#YourTable','Date','sum([Result])[]','Name',null
```

**Returns**

[image]

**The Stored Procedure**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[prc-Pivot] (
    @Source varchar(1000),          -- Any Table or Select Statement
    @PvotCol varchar(250),          -- Field name or expression ie. Month(Date)
    @Summaries varchar(250),        -- aggfunction(aggValue)[optionalTitle]
    @GroupBy varchar(250),          -- Optional additional Group By 
    @OtherCols varchar(500) )       -- Optional Group By or aggregates
AS

Set NoCount On
Set Ansi_Warnings Off

Declare @Vals varchar(max),@SQL varchar(max);
Set @Vals = ''
Set @OtherCols= IsNull(', ' + @OtherCols,'')
Set @Source = case when @Source Like 'Select%' then @Source else 'Select * From '+@Source end
Create Table #TempPvot  (Pvot varchar(100))
Insert Into #TempPvot
Exec ('Select Distinct Convert(varchar(100),' + @PvotCol + ') as Pvot FROM (' + @Source + ') A')
Select @Vals = @Vals + ', isnull(' + Replace(Replace(@Summaries,'(','(CASE WHEN ' + @PvotCol + '=''' + Pvot +  ''' THEN '),')[', ' END),0) As [' + Pvot ) From #TempPvot Order by Pvot
Drop Table #TempPvot
Set @SQL = Replace('Select ' + Isnull(@GroupBy,'') + @OtherCols + @Vals + ' From (' + @Source + ') PvtFinal ' + case when Isnull(@GroupBy,'')<>'' then 'Group By ' + @GroupBy + ' Order by ' + @GroupBy else '' end,'Select , ','Select ')
--Print @SQL
Exec (@SQL)


Set NoCount Off
Set Ansi_Warnings on
```

Comment: Bingo! Thank you very much John. Your procedure gives the columns as I needed. Also, it's really universal. For the source parameter I put SELECT statement with WHERE conditions instead of table name. So it will be usefull for the future. You helped me a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Just use conditional aggregation:

```
select name,
       max(case when date = '2010-01-01' then result end) as result_20100101,
       max(case when date = '2010-07-04' then result end) as result_20100704
from tbl_results
where . . . 
group by name;
```

Then upgrade your system to a supported database.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The problem is I can't use fixed dates values in statement, it can be different number of columns.

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
SELECT *  FROM
(
    SELECT A.Name,A.Date,A.Result 
    FROM your_table A
    --WHERE A.Name = 'Name01'
) A
PIVOT
(
    SUM(Result)
    FOR Date IN ([2010-01-01],[2010-07-04])
)PVT
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I try it, but I get only null values in the dates columns (no result). Also I can't use fixed dates values, it can be different number of columns.